# combine multiple GridSearchCV instances

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I could save time by splitting up parameters that I would like to put into a GridSearchCV so that I could have further parallelization of parameter space exploration (beyond setting `n_jobs`).

For instance instead of:

```py
all_params = {'n_estimators' : [10, 20], 'min_samples_leaf' : [10, 20]}
```

I could create two parameter sets that would still cover the same parameter space, and send off two independent jobs to run at the same time:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

# job 1 (independent script from job 2)
params1 = {'n_estimators' : [10], 'min_samples_leaf' : [10, 20]}
grid_search1 = GridSearchCV(..., param_grid=params1)

# job 2 (independent script from job 1)
params2 = {'n_estimators' : [20], 'min_samples_leaf' : [10, 20]}
grid_search2 = GridSearchCV(..., param_grid=params2)
```

and then I would like  combined them:

```py
grid_search1 = # load pkl from GridSearchCV(..., param_grid=params1)
grid_search2 = # load pkl from GridSearchCV(..., param_grid=params2)

full_grid = grid_search1 + grid_search2

print(full_grid.best_params_)
```

I realize I could iterate somthing like `grid_search1.cv_results_` and compare with `grid_search2.cv_results_` but looking for something cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in method to directly combine `GridSearchCV` objects, but we can try to combine `cv_results_` into a single `dataframes` then we will find the best parameter from there.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(grid_search1.cv_results_)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(grid_search2.cv_results_)

full_grid_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)

best_index = full_grid_df['mean_test_score'].idxmax()

print(full_grid_df.loc[best_index, 'params'])
```